# Заказчики-обманщики

Tags: работа

Работал нормально 1.5 года, никто не обмановал, все оплачивали. Но, недавно попался заказчик, который не заплатил мне, хоть и речь всего о 400р., всёравно обидно. Ну заказчки не достаточно умно поступил, доступы оставил, я залил туда файлик, который может выполнять sql запросы, удалять файлы, заливать. Но кое-что не продумал, это бекап. При бекапе этот файл удаляется. Ну и доступы уже сменили. Пытался я и почту вломать и jooml`y, потом всё-таки забил) Теперь делаю так: сначала заливаю файл, после уже делаю задание, в таком случае при бекапе файл будет оставаться. Ну я, как бы, поделился своим методом, а как вы действуете?

Comment: А у меня есть знакомый, который пару раз реально ездил с битой в гости и получал 200-400% от суммы `^_^`

Comment: Ха, малодец) Только вот попались бы какие-нибудь мафиози)))) И всё...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошая полемика по теме вопроса уже проскакивала на [**хабре.**](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/freelance/129974/)

---

*Пожалуй, даже, процитирую ответ одного из пользователей:*

> Иногда подрабатываю фрилансом: или сайты делаю или на C# проги пишу. И в любом случае делаю защиту от кидка. В случае с сайтами у меня до оплаты остается доступ к админке. В случае с программами вставляю блок который проверяет определенный файл с кодом на моем сервере. Если до файла не достучаться (в том случае если программу фаерволом прикрыли) или если код не верный, то программа перестает работать. Код может стать не верным если я его у себя на сервере исправлю, а сделаю это в том случае если меня попытаются кинуть. После оплаты все бэкдоры убераю.
> Что касается паяния плат, даже не знаю… Но что-нибудь в этом же духе можно было придумать

---

Как вариант - работа через гаранта *(например, на `freelance.ru`)*. Тут, разумеется, **тоже есть свои детали и нюансы,** но в большинстве случаев схема работает неплохо.

Comment: Спасибо, навёл на мысль сделать API по этому поводу))

Comment: Самое гнусное (было не так давно) - это когда сайт у тебя на хостинге, ты все контролируешь, а заказчик за день-два до сдачи "передумал" и слушать ничего не хочет, а письменного договора у вас не было. Вот это круто. Ну, я себя успокаиваю тем, что больше такого не допущу, но сами понимаете, неприятненько) Так что либо аванс, либо мутным сразу путевочку до ближайшего столба в зубы.

Answer (score 1):

Работаю на 2 условиях.

1. Аванс.
2. Сайт у меня на сервере до победного завершения.

Comment: Ну, а если правки какие-то, или доработка. Так уже не сделаешь. А на аванс врядли кто будет соглашаться, большая конкуренция.

Comment: Среди УГ программистов - возможно... Незнаю как у вас, а в украине дела с программистами примерно <a href="http://delo.ua/education/samye-vostrebovannye-specialisty-po-itogam-sentjabrja-165783/">такие</a>...<br>
Естественно есть куча народа на фрилансе, там конкуренция большая, конечно среди тех кто готов работать за еду...

Comment: Я уже 100 раз убеждался что если не дают аванс значит жди беды, и лутше с такими дела не иметь.

Comment: на 100% солидарен :)